# Trouble with joinning tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

Here is my database tables, i want to echo everything with join, but its dosnt work.

Products table:

```
id category_id img name price price_action in_stock category description youtube
```

---

Category table:

```
 category_id category_name
```

---

Here is my code, how to want list everything, but its dosnt work:

```
<?php
    include ("../db_config.php");

    $sql[0] = "SELECT * FROM products RIGHT JOIN category ON category.category_name=products.category_id";

    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql[0]) or die(mysqli_error());
    echo '
    <div id="nlist"><table class="list"><tr>
    <td><b>Name</b></td>
    <td><b>Price</b></td>
    <td><b>Category</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>';

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "
            <td>$record[name]</td>
            <td>$record[price]</td>
            <td>$record[category_name]</td>
            </tr>";    
        }
    }
    else 
        echo "sikertelen";
?>
```

Comment: You're joining on the NAME = ID.  That is likely incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are joining on the wrong columns.  The NAME and the ID will likely not match.

```
$sql[0] = "SELECT * FROM products RIGHT JOIN category ON category.category_id=products.category_id";
```

I can tell this because you show the category_id in both tables.

Comment: Yes, its worked. Thank you very much :) Seems like im too tired for this :(

Comment: Eggsellent!  (please accept the answer, unless you can't)

Comment: 4 minute and i can :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use inner join if the keys always match

```
SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN category ON category.category_name=products.category_id
```

or left if the key don't match

```
SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN category ON category.category_name=products.category_id
```

If all the keys match the right join return nothings